# Site look changed

Tags: sharepoint-online

On thursday I was changing a few settings, but can't remember what I've changed anymore.

Here is the **old look**:

[image]

And here is the **new look**:

[image]

So, could you tell me how to get the old look back?

Comment: Did you try to perform Change the look? You can navigate to _"SharePoint Site Settings > Change the look"_ and apply **Seattle** Site layout.

Comment: Oh no. That was really to easy... Well, changed back the look to 'Office' and I have it back. I guess changing some settings made my subsite inherit the root site look. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate to *"SharePoint Site Settings > Change the look"* and apply **Seattle** Site layout.